# Combine two fields into string in JSON using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I would like to combine two fields in a MYSQL database into one for output in JSON using PHP. The query draws from two tables:

The first table looks like

```
comments
id|userid|comment
1|1|Agree
1|2|Disagree
```

The second table of users looks like:

```
users
id|username
1|Bob
2|Joe
```

Here is my current code (stripped down):

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id,u.username,c.comment FROM comments `c` ";
$sql.= "LEFT JOIN users `u` ON c.userid = u.id 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
//Note there is protection against sql injection and the actual parameterized query is way more complicated: I am simplifying here  

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $comments[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array('comments'=>$comments));
```

It returns JSON that looks like:

```
"comments":[{"id":"1","username":"Joe","comment":"Agree"},{"id":"2","username":"Bob","comment":"Disagree"}]
```

I would like to create combine the id and name of the user into one field to get something like:

```
"comments: [{"user": "1,Joe","comment":"Agree"},{"user":"2,Bob","comment":"Disagree"}]
```

Can I use concat? Would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Well, instead of directly assigning the entire row `$comments[] = $row`, build a new array with the combined values from the row as you desire and then encode that one? Seems like a very straightforward task.

Comment: `concat(u.id, ',', u.username) as combo`. Additionally `actual parameterized query` is false, `mysql_` doesn't support parameterized queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Dharman, did you actually read the question and the part about parameterized queries?  That link has nothing to do with the question. Nick and user3783243 provided good answers.

Comment: While @Dharman's link doesn't answer your direct question, following his advice will save you potential big trouble down the road, and you might want to read the link in detail to see why.

Comment: You don't really understand the issue yet, but if you advance further into PHP programming likely you will. Hopefully this will be in the not too distant future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the data from the query in the form you want:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', u.id, u.username) AS user,  c.comment FROM comments `c` ";
$sql.= "LEFT JOIN users `u` ON c.userid = u.id";
```

You can also use `CONCAT(u.id, ',', u.username)` instead of `CONCAT_WS`; the only difference is that `CONCAT_WS` ignores `NULL` values, where `CONCAT` will return `NULL` if *any* value is `NULL`. The difference can be seen in this [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6959803/1).

Comment: is there a difference between CONCAT_WS and CONCAT?

Comment: @zztop `CONCAT_WS` will ignore `NULL` values. In this case it probably won't a difference compared to `CONCAT(u.id, ',', u.username)` but in others it may.